# primefaces fileupload preview not working if extension is in uppercase

Tags: regex, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I am trying to use primefaces advanced fileupload, however I have noticed that when the extension is in uppercase the preview does not work. Below is the upload code.

```
<p:fileUpload  fileUploadListener="${myController.handleFileUpload}"
                                               mode="advanced" id="fileupload"                                              
                                               sizeLimit="2000000"  uploadLabel="Add" 
                                               dragDropSupport="false" previewWidth="190" 
                                               label="Browse" style="width: 600px;height: 200px" 
                                               required="true"  update="fileDescId"
                                               allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|GIF|JPG|JPEG|PNG)$/i"/>
```

Searching on google has not yielded much, I found that adding `/i` at the end of allowTypes makes the regex case insensitive but still the preview does not show. If I click upload it upload successfully even if the preview did not show, but I need the preview because a description of the image is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out your problem. The problem in the file [\META-INF\resources\primefaces\fileupload\fileupload.js](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/fileupload/fileupload.js). Preview images are only available for png, jpg and gif files and for this there is a check:

```js
//preview
if($this.isCanvasSupported() && window.File && window.FileReader && $this.IMAGE_TYPES.test(file.name))
```

and pattern:

```
IMAGE_TYPES: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/
```

As you can see in this place lacks the flag for case insensitive validation. So i manually add this flag

```
IMAGE_TYPES: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
```

and preview started working as it should. I checked several times, cleaned and put the flag, everything works. 
So I sent the corresponding [patch](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7625).

Comment: Thanks @0x5a4d it worked. Hoping Primefaces applies the patch soon so I don't have to override it.